# C# - Datagridview - Counting the records in DGV

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

So i'm working on a school project and I'm close to finish but I have a problem. My "program" is for music and I have different genres. My task is to somehow sort the artist by music and count them all. I mean, when you would click on "Sort by genre" in menustrip, a messagebox would show saying "rock 4, pop 3 etc" the numbers refers to artist, on how many are in Datagridview. But I have no idea how to write that code. So if you guys have an example I would be really happy to know it. My code now looks like this. Some Slovenian words but, don't mind them.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;

   namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void konecToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close(); // ugasnemo okno :)
    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // validacija vnosa datuma, album ne sme biti izdan 2013(ker pač ne sme bit, ne se razubrjat)
        if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Year.ToString() == "2013")
            errorProvider1.SetError(dateTimePicker1, "Year must be earlyer that 2013");
        else
            errorProvider1.SetError(dateTimePicker1, "");
    }

    private void bCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { // brisanje vnosa na panelu
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        comboBox1.Text = "";
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today;
        radioButton1.Checked = false;
        radioButton2.Checked = false;
        radioButton3.Checked = false;
        radioButton4.Checked = false;
    }

    private void bAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //vnašanje iz panela v datagridwiev.
        string Zvrst = "";
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
            Zvrst = radioButton1.Text;
        if (radioButton2.Checked)
            Zvrst = radioButton2.Text;
        if (radioButton3.Checked)
            Zvrst = radioButton3.Text;
        if (radioButton4.Checked)
            Zvrst = radioButton4.Text;
        //napaka če niso vsa polja vnešena !!
        if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "" || comboBox1.Text == "" || Zvrst == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Prosimo vnesite vrednosti!");
            errorProvider1.SetError(bDodaj, "Prosimo vnesite vrednosti");
        }
        else
        dGVKos.Rows.Add(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, comboBox1.Text, Zvrst, dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")); 

    }

    private void dGVKos_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {//deletes current row
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 6)
            dGVKos.Rows.Remove(dGVKos.CurrentRow);
        if (e.ColumnIndex == this.dGVKos.Columns[7].Index)
        {
            textBox1.Text = dGVKos.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dGVKos.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dGVKos.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            comboBox1.Text = dGVKos.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            if
            (dGVKos.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "Pop") { radioButton1.Checked = true; }
            else { radioButton1.Checked = false; }
            if (dGVKos.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "Rock") { radioButton2.Checked = true; } 
            else { radioButton2.Checked = false; }
            if (dGVKos.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "Metal") { radioButton3.Checked = true; } 
            else { radioButton3.Checked = false; }
            if (dGVKos.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "Slo/YU") { radioButton4.Checked = true; } 
            else { radioButton4.Checked = false; }
            dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dGVKos.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value);


        }
    }

    private void shraniToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //saves everything to .txt file (lahko uporabimo tudi saveFileDialog
        StreamWriter pisi = File.CreateText("Glasba.txt");
        //preverimo če je kašna vrstica v dGvKos
        if (dGVKos.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            //premikamo se po vsrsticah in jih zapisujemo v datoteko
            for (int i = 0; i < dGVKos.Rows.Count; i++)
                pisi.WriteLine(dGVKos.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + " " +
                    dGVKos.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + " " +
                    dGVKos.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value + " " +
                    dGVKos.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + " " +
                    dGVKos.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value + " " +
                    dGVKos.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value + " ");
            pisi.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Glasbeniki so vnešeni v datoteko Glasba.txt v mapi debug");
        } // če ni vrstic se nam izpiše ->
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Ni nobene vrstice");

    }

    private void infoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Program je namenjen vnašanju najljubših glasbenikov in njihovih albumov. Izvajalce se potem da razvrstit tudi po sami zvrsti s pomočjo postavke v menuju" +
           " " + "V polja vnesemo željene vrednosti in dodamo vnos katerega lahko urejamo, brišemo itd. Pri datumu mora letnica biti manjša od 2013.");
    }

    private void sortBygenreToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please show us the sample data image? The code you gave is totally irrelevant here

Comment: Well not enough reputation. :( All I need to know is how to sort/count something from datagridview. Like you have 10 musicians, different genres and you need to count how many are rockers, how many pop, etc ?

Comment: Ok I give you an example with sample data. Just wait for few minutes !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the output:
[image]

Here is the code to count:

```
            int CountRock = 0;
            int CountPop = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (!row.IsNewRow)  //last row is new row containing null data, so we won't check this one
                {
                    if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "Rock")    //cell[1] defines that the index of column is '1'
                        CountRock++;
                    else if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "Pop")
                        CountPop++;
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(CountRock + " , " + CountPop);//Displaying the output
```

You can simplify the `if-statements` by checking only starting char:

```
if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().StartsWith("R"))
```

In the same way you can write your own **sorting** logic by just using the `for` or `foreach` loops.

Comment: You are the best, thank you mate it works perfectly ! I apreciate the help and sorry for bad english :)

Comment: @user3083561 If it helped. You can use it as answer